# How do I digitally sign a pdf into a separate file on C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

How do I digitally sign a pdf into a separate file on C#?
I have worked code with iText lib, but this is internal digital signature.
I want digital signature in separate hash file. So that you can check this digital signature later.
output like:
1. output.pdf
2. output.pdf.sig
This is possible? This is possible with iText?

Comment: If you start with the msdn article on  [crypographic signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptographic-signatures). Is there something specific you are having truble with?

Comment: *"This is possible?"* - yes. Look for generic signing articles. - *"This is possible with iText?"* - as you want to sign the pdf externally, there is no need for a pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

The following [demo code](http://www.visualstudiotutorial.net/digital-signature-implementation) might get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileName = args[0];

    //  create signature
    DSACryptoServiceProvider signer = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
    var bytes = ReadBytes(fileName);
    var signature = signer.SignData(bytes);
    var publicKey = signer.ToXmlString(false);

    //  we could write this signature to a separate file
    Console.WriteLine("Digital signature: " + Convert.ToBase64String(signature));

    //  verify signature
    DSACryptoServiceProvider verifier = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();

    verifier.FromXmlString(publicKey);

    if (verifier.VerifyData(bytes, signature))
        Console.WriteLine("Signature OK");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Signature not OK");
}

static byte[] ReadBytes(string fileName)
{
    using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
    {
        return reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
    }
}
```